# Proving that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M-m$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just looking for some feedback on my proof. We are assuming that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and that $f$ is a bounded function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If $M = \sup \{f(x)|x \in [a,b]\}$ and $m = \inf \{f(x)|x \in [a,b]\},$ prove that for any $x,y \in [a,b],$

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M-m.$$

My approach: Assume this is false, i.e. that there exist real numbers $x$ and $y$ in the interval for which $M-m<|f(x)-f(y)|.$ Then, we have that

$$M-m<f(x)-f(y)<m-M,$$

and so $M-m<m-M,$ a contradiction. Thus, $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M-m.$

Comment: Where are you getting $f(x)-f(y)<m-M$ from?

Comment: Isn't it the case that when $|u| < c$, then $-c<u<c$?

Comment: Yes,  but you are assuming $c<|u|$, the opposite side

Comment: Picture $m, M$ on number line with $m\leq M$. Now think of two points $A, B$ corresponding to $f(x), f(y) $ in the segment between $m, M$. The distance between $A, B$ can't exceed the length of segment between $m, M$. Essentially this is about showing that $a\leq c\leq d\leq b$ implies $|c-d|\leq b-a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$M-m<f(x)-f(y)<m-M$$
is wrong. It should be $$m-M<f(x)-f(y)<M-m.$$

Correct proof: $f(x)-f(y) \leq M-m $ and  $f(x)-f(y) \geq m-M$ so $m-M \leq f(x)-f(y) \leq M-m$. Can you finish the proof?